# Get resolve variable and pass to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi I created a model named billerModel and a route that has a resolve with a variable of billers. Now I want to retrieve and assign this variable inside my controller but I get this billerData unknown provider error. Below are my code for the route:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$httpProvider",'$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when("/billers", {
        templateUrl: 'admin/billers/index.html',
        controller: 'billerController',
        resolve: {
            billerData: function(billerModel) {
                return billerModel.getData();
            }
        }
    });
```

Below is my code for the model

```
app.factory('billerModel', ['$http', '$cookies', function($http, $cookies) {
    return {
      getData: function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'billers'
        });
      }
    }
}]);
```

Below is my controller code that gives me the error

```
app.controller('billerController', ['$scope', 'billerData',  
   function($scope, billerData){
       $scope.billers = billerData;

}]);
```

I also tried to remove the ng-controller from my view but if I do this then I get an error of unknown variable

```
<div style="text-align: left;" ng-controller="billerController">
    {{ billers }}
</div>
```

[image]

Below is a jsfiddle but I'm not familiar on how to use it but the basic structure is included here
https://jsfiddle.net/bd06cctd/1/

Comment: You create factory `billerModel`. But try inject in controller `billerData`. Change inject into `billerModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolve data in `.when` blocks is only injectable into controllers defined by the `.when` block. Child controllers injected by the `ng-controller` directive can not inject resolve data.

Also if you inject `billerController` in the `.when` block **and** with the `ng-controller` directive in the `.when` block template, then the controller will be instantiated **twice**.

The `$routeProvider` also makes resolve data available on the view scope on the `$resolve` property. Child controllers instantiated by the `ng-controller` directive can use that.

```
app.controller('childController', ['$scope',  
   function($scope){
       $scope.billers = $scope.$resolve.billerData;
}]);
```

Controllers instantiated by the `ng-controller` directive will find the `$resolve` property by prototypical inheritance from the view scope.

From the Docs:

> - resolve - `{Object.<string, Function>=}` - An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and `$routeChangeSuccess` event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the `$routeChangeError` event is fired. For easier access to the resolved dependencies from the template, **the resolve map will be available on the scope of the route, under `$resolve`** (by default) or a custom name specified by the `resolveAs` property.

-- [AngularJS $routeProvider API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: You're a life saver that explains it clearly. Thank you sooo much

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing:

```
app.factory('billerModel', ['$http', '$cookies', function($http, $cookies) {
return {
  getData: function() {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'billers'
    });
  }
}
}]);
```

to

```
app.factory('billerModel', ['$http', '$cookies', function($http, $cookies) {
    return {
      getData: $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'billers'
        });
    }
}]);
```

You're returning an anonymous function, not a Promise

Comment: No luck on this same problem.

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: There seems to be a couple of issues with the fiddle:

```fiddle.jshell.net/:46 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
angular.min.js:17 Uncaught Error: No module: app```